# SBT high cpu usage when run as ~ run

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, cpu-usage

I have a **Play 2.5** project and I'm running it with `sbt` with `~ run` but it consumes 30% of CPU just to run.

I'm using **InteliJ** to run the project with parameters:

```
-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dsbt.task.forcegc=false
```

Any hints on this?

[image: Screenshot of CPU performance]

Comment: You're showing Intellij's CPU usage though, not SBT's... The SBT is `xsbt.boot.Boot (pid 7000)` on your screenshot. I mean, Intellij forks SBT, it doesn't run in the same JVM.

Comment: exactly on the right part there is xsbt. boot. Boot jvm graphs... look more carefully

Comment: oh, you're absolutely right

Comment: I have the same problem with Eclipse, so I guess it's not Intellij's fault

Answer (score 1):

I am currently writing my Scala certification and I confirm that Intellij uses a lot of CPU  whatever the operation (package update, exec etc...) so it looks just  normal.

Comment: hmm I've updated the scala plugin in Intelij it looks better but it consumes still 14% of processor constantly when sbt ~run is used ... is there really no workaround?